# How to change the Assemby and the Object type on the Newtonsoft.Json serialization/deserialization? Am using .NET MVC 3 and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, json, asp.net-mvc-3, json.net

I've looked and tried every single solution posted here, with no avail.

My problem is:

- On a web solution (ASP.NET MVC 3 C# / Razor), I'm using Json.Net to serialize the data displayed on some reports, to be able to send it over to a WPF application.
  These reports results are a collection of Model objects.
- I have the same Model objects on the WPF application, so when I deserialize the Json string, I would like to bind the results accordingly (keeping the original Model object).
- The Assembly name and Object type are different on each end (Web / App) - different namespaces.

Here's what I've tried so far:

On the web solution:

```
// MyModel
public class MyModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
// data = IEnumerable<MyModel>
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.ToArray(), data.ToArray().GetType(), 
    new JsonSerializerSettings 
    { 
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    });
```

On the app:

```
// MyModel
public class MyModel
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Name")]            
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var jsonArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(e.jsonObject,
    null,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            Binder = new MySerializationBinder()
        });
```

...

```
public class MySerializationBinder : DefaultSerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        return typeof(MyModel);
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me a hand on this, please?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

As per @Marc Gravell comment:

I forgot to mention the main issue here. I need to send the Object type across to the WPF app, because the listener will be expecting data from many reports - which are collections of different Models. So, when binding it back, I know which Object should be binded.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what the problem is that you are trying to solve; normally, the resultant JSON *does not contain* any type information - it will just be `{"Id":"123,"Name":"Foo"}` - as such, you do not **require** any special model binding - that will deserialize into the app's `MyModel` *just fine*. What is the problem you are having? Why are you including type names in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stand by my original answer - type information in serialization data is *just really messy* - it would be far better to change the code *not to need this*, but to "fix" it (not sure that is the right word) - look carefully at the `typeName` - it isn't always what you are expecting:

```
public class MySerializationBinder : DefaultSerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        switch(typeName)
        {
            case "WebSolution.MyModel[]": return typeof(Application.MyModel[]);
            case "WebSolution.MyModel": return typeof(Application.MyModel);
            default: return base.BindToType(assemblyName, typeName);
        }

    }
}
```

Incidentally, once the array type is known, the element type is implicit - so you can save some effort by only including the array type:

```
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Arrays
        }
```

But I still advise: don't do it this way.

---

The "mistake" here is including the full type names in the first place; the presence of type names in json should usually be the warning sign of a code-smell. Remove those, and there is *nothing to do* - it *just works*:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // here imagine we're in the web tier, serializing
        var data = GetData();
        var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            data.ToArray(), Formatting.None);
        // now imagine we're at the application, deserializing
        var appData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Application.MyModel[]>(
            jsonData);
        // and it all works fine
    }
    static IEnumerable<WebSolution.MyModel> GetData()
    {
        yield return new WebSolution.MyModel { Id = 123, Name = "abc" };
        yield return new WebSolution.MyModel { Id = 456, Name = "def" };
    }
}

namespace WebSolution
{
    // MyModel
    public class MyModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Application
{
    // MyModel
    public class MyModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my update, please. The problem is I don't know which Model is coming serialized to be able to deserialize back into it. That's why I'm including the $type when serializing.

Comment: Being honest, I'm quite new to all of this, so it's great that you pointed out something that could cause me problems in the future. Living and learning! I'll give a go following your example and see if I can achieve the result I'm expecting. Thank you very much.