# How to deserialize json object after the class has been renamed?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have an object previously serialized using the [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

Class for the object:

```
[DataContract]
public class AttackDto : DtoBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string AttackingPlayer { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string AttackedPlayer { get; set; }
}
```

Object in serialized form:

```
{
  "$type": "SerializationDemo.AttackDto, SerializationDemo",
  "AttackingPlayer": "John",
  "AttackedPlayer": "Dave"
}
```

Now i want to rename "AttackDto" to "AttackEvent", but do not want to break the deserialization logic for json, that was stored before renaming.

Is it possible to do some kind of type forwarding, so that all serialized objects with type: SerializationDemo.AttackDto are actually deserialized as AttackEvent?

Comment: I don't have time to write up a complete answer at the moment, but I think you should be able to create a custom [SerializationBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm) to translate the old class name to the new type.

Comment: @Brian Rogers You're awesome! Creating a custom ISerializationBinder and implementing BindToType() solves this problem.

Comment: Related: [How to change the Assemby and the Object type on the Newtonsoft.Json serialization/deserialization? Am using .NET MVC 3 and WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17485955).